# Problems downloading dotnet30 and dotnet35 on playonmac/playonlinux through wine 2.11 or 1.83

Tags: .net, macos, download, wine

I've been trying to install some game on my mac, osu to be more specific, following this guide: https://gist.github.com/Francesco149/a2f796683a4e5195458f4bb171d88eb0, which was made for linux. Up until the very end, everything goes fine, but once I'm at the point where I need to start up the game, it crashes. I installed dotnet20, now the game launches, but blackscreens and has no audio. So I tried installing dotnet30 and 35 in order to see if those were the issue, and both the winetricks command in a terminal and the default playonmac install (in install components) fail with a download error. Is there any ways I can fix this? I will put a screenshot of the error screens below.

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot for any help you can provide :)